# In quantum metrology, how do we achieve unbiased estimator in the local unbiased formalism?

Tags: quantum-metrology

In quantum metrology, the main goal is to estimate some unknown parameter to the limit of quantum mechanics. Suppose there's a unitary quantum channel $U_{\theta}=e^{-i\theta \sigma _z}$ with $\theta$ an unknown parameter to be estimated. That is, we can prepare some initial state $\rho$ and let it pass through the channel to get a state $\rho _{\theta}=U_{\theta}\rho U_{\theta}^{\dagger}$. Then we do some measurements to $\rho _{\theta}$ and infer $\theta$ from the measurement results. The optimal measurement scheme for the unitary process normally does not depend on the unknown parameter, that is, for $\theta=0$ or $\theta=0.1$, we can use the same initial state and same measurement and the same inferring method to estimate $\theta$.

However, if the process with parameter is not unitary, e.g. we further have some influence of the noise, then our aim now becomes to estimate $\theta$ from the quantum channel $\mathcal{E} _{\theta}$. In this case, the optimal scheme in general depends on the parameter $\theta$ and we might can't find an unbiased estimator(our inferring method or more formally, a function from measurement data to the possible value of $\theta$) for all possible value of $\theta$. Hence we require our scheme to be locally unbiased, that is we only require our estimator to be unbiased in the neighborhood of the true value, sometimes only unbiased only in the true value. Even though some papers say that we can deal with such parameter-dependent schemes with the adaptive method. That is, suppose we have $N>>1$ measurement results, we use $n_1$ results to estimate $\theta$ with some trivial scheme and use this estimate of $\theta$ to update our scheme(since our scheme depends on $\theta$). We then use the new scheme with $n_2$ results...

**My problem is**, since our scheme is only unbiased in the true value, how can the adaptive method works since taking our estimated $\theta$(which can be biased) into our scheme might not generate an unbiased guess?

**Edit**. I mentioned that "some papers say that we can deal with such parameter-dependent schemes with the adaptive method. That is..." In fact, some papers mention the words "adaptive" while do not mention how to implement it so the *That is* part is mine. The similar adaptive scheme is mentioned below eq(9) of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2001.11742). I quoted it here for your convenience(emphasize is mine):

> If the true parameter $\boldsymbol{\theta}$ is close to some known value $\boldsymbol{\theta}_0$, we may look for locally unbiased estimators around this point; the following estimator saturates the CR bound and hence is optimal at $\boldsymbol{\theta}_0$
> $$
> \tilde{\boldsymbol{\theta}}(m)=\boldsymbol{\theta}_0+\left.\frac{1}{p_{\boldsymbol{\theta}}(m)} F^{-1} \boldsymbol{\nabla} p_{\boldsymbol{\theta}}(m)\right|_{\boldsymbol{\theta}=\boldsymbol{\theta}_0} .
> $$
> However, with the exception of models belonging to the class of exponential family of probability distributions, the estimator will depend explicitly on $\boldsymbol{\theta}_0$ and is not optimal away from this point. This drawback can be remedied in a scenario where many independent samples are available, where the following two stage **adaptive** procedure can be applied: a 'reasonable' preliminary estimator $\boldsymbol{\theta}_0$ is computed on a subsample, while the remaining samples are used to compute the final estimator by using the above formula.

Comment: Not an answer yet, but note that, in general, the optimal measurement scheme for the unitary case *does* depend on the parameter! The optimal state does not depend on the parameter. This is easy to see by allowing your optimal measurement scheme to include an extra, known unitary that "unbiases" your measurement

Comment: Another comment: if the noise and unitary channels commute, which is true for some types of noise such as depolarization but not all types of noise, then one can incorporate an extra unitary in the measurement scheme to "unbias" the measurement

Comment: I'm not sure about the general case. But if the goal is eg to estimate a linear functional of the state (ie essentially the expectation value of an observable), then you can generally find estimators that are unbiased (provided the measurement is IC; and also assuming a single-parameter estimation scenario I think), and then this adaptive reasoning makes sense because you always can find a (globally) unbiased measurement, and the adaptiveness allows to switch to a more efficient unbiased measurement after the first measurements. A relevant ref here is Zhu's work https://arxiv.org/abs/1404.3453

Comment: The answer is given in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9808009) which is cited by [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2001.11742).